# Java eclipse does not recognize the import org.apache.poi package that is already imported with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven, apache-poi

I am trying to create an excel in java with apache poi, I am using spring boot and thymeleaf, I have already imported the dependencies in the pom.xml file and update it in my eclipse, the dependencies are in my project, when I run the command mvn clean install everything seems to be Okay, but when importing it to my java class, it can't find it, I already tried to change the version of the apache-poi library, but it didn't work. I leave here some reference data:

[this is the class that I want to inport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPY02.png)

[eclipse does not recognize the jara apache-poi class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17R3h.png)

this is the code of my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>mx.com.telcel</groupId>
    <artifactId>detalladoVentas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>detalladoVentas</name>
    <description>Generación de reportes sisap</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
            </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- START Bibliotecas necesarias para el desarrollo de reportes en Excel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END Bibliotecas necesarias para el desarrollo de reportes en Excel -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What do you think is the problem? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You have `<scope>runtime</scope>` for several dependencies in your POM. Can you explain in your own words what that instruction does?

Comment: I didn't know what it meant, now I see that this scope indicates that dependency is not necessary for compilation, but for execution. Thank you very much

Comment: Great, you figured it out yourself and added a proper answer. Don't forget to accept your own answer (after the 2-day wait period is over) so that this question doesn't come up as unanswered in searches. Also, always include textual content as `formatted` text – use only images when it makes sense – and then prefer to embed the image directly into your question (and not as a link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question in case someone finds it useful in the future: 
I didn't know what

```
< scope > runtime < /scope >
```

meant, now I see that this scope indicates that dependency is not required for compilation, but for execution.It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath. 
so the solution was to just remove this tag.

Answer (score -1):

you need not to add scope of dependencies of Apache POI.
check it from here

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/4.1.2

I use them in gradle and their scope is compile time by default

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/4.1.2

Comment: i tried this solution but the erroe is the same, my java class not recognize the package org.apache.poi.* , I don´t know if i´m missing some eclipse configuration.